# how to create vertex groups from materials using python?

Tags: scripting

I have assigned different materials to a single mesh. I want to create vertex groups from the materials assigned. Is it possible to create vertex groups from materials using python?

Comment: i see that you tagged "scripting".. do you mean that you wanna do It by code? or by 3D view?

Comment: Yes how to do it through python code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script adds the verts assigned to the face assigned to a material to a vert group with the materials name.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
obj = context.active_object

for index, slot in enumerate(obj.material_slots):
    #select the verts from faces with material index
    if not slot.material:
        # empty slot
        continue
    verts = [v for f in obj.data.polygons 
           if f.material_index == index for v in f.vertices]
    if len(verts):
        vg = obj.vertex_groups.get(slot.material.name)
        if vg is None: 
            vg = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=slot.material.name)
        vg.add(verts, 1.0, 'ADD')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually. Just hover over a vertex and click "l" and then f6 and choose material instead of seam or sharp.[image]

After that assign the selected vertices to a vertex group.

Comment: I am aware of this method thanks. I wanted to do it through script.